# Change an " If else statement " to a switch statement

Tags: java, ide, switch-statement

was wondering if anyone could help me change an " If else statement " to a "switch" 
Well c the pseudo code is.
Please help .

```
IF month is 1,2, or 3, season = "Winter
Else if month is 4, 5, or 6, season = "Spring"
Else if month is 7,8, 9, season = "Summer"
Else if month is 10,11, or 12, season = "Fall"
If season is "Winter", season = "Spring"
Else if season is "Spring", season = "Summer"
Else if season is "Summer", season = "Fall"
Else season = "Winter"
```

2.My code is

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
    public class mylab

     {
      public static void main(String[] args) 

      { Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int month;
        int day;
        String season= "seasons";


         System.out.print("type a two digit month");
         System.out.print(" and day");
         month = in.nextInt();
         day = in.nextInt();


        String fall = " fall";
        String winter = " winter ";
        String summer = " summer";
        String spring = " spring";

      System.out.print(" Month="+ month +" Day= "+day);

      if( month <= 3)
      { System.out.println(" Winter");   
        season= winter; }
        else if ( month <=6)
        { System.out.println(" Spring ");   
          season=spring;  }

         else if ( month<= 9)
        { System.out.println(" Summer ");  
           season= spring; }

          else if ( month<=12)
         { System.out.println(" Fall");   
            season= fall; }
```

3.I just need to change the 1st part to a switch statement.
This is what I have so far

```
switch( month )
  { case 1: season= " winter";if ( month <= 3) ;break;
    case 2: season= " spring"; if ( month <= 6) ;break;
    case 3: season = " summer"; if (month  <= 9); break;
    case 4: season= " fall"; if (month <= 12); break ;
  }
```

,but it is not working .

Comment: It wouldn't work since that's wholly invalid syntax.  I would encourage you to look at the [Java Trails](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for this.

Comment: Smells like homework for a class to me...

Answer (score 2):

> IF month is 1,2, or 3, season = "Winter

Would simply become...

```
String season = "";
switch (month) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        season = "Winter";
        break;
    case ...: // etc...
}
```

`case` will fall through to the next `case` unless there is a `break`

Take a look at [The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

How about some integer division?

```
switch( (month + 2) / 12 ) {
    case 1:
        // winter
        break;
    case 2:
        // spring
        break; // WOOHOO SPRING BREAK!
    case 3:
        // summer
        break;
    case 4:
        // fall
        break;  // winter is coming...
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: So, I changed it a bit , but now the second part is not working

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. You need two switch statements.  One for the first if/else chain, and one for the second.  (Though you could easily fold the two chains into one!)
2. The syntax of a switch statement is illustrated in the Java Tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).
3. The following statement does nothing:

   ```
     if ( month <= 3) ;
   ```

   It says "test if month is less or equal to 3, and then execute the empty statement.  This is a *"gotcha!"* in Java syntax ... and one of the reasons that some people think that you should *always* use curly brackets with if and loop statements in Java and similar languages.